# How to copy files to a folder where the folder's name changes daily

Tags: python

So I've got some files located at "source_path". I'm trying to copy them to "dest_path" and "dest_path2" . "Dest_path2" changes everyday, as the full folder name includes the variable "today2", which is just today's date formatted in a particular way.

I can get the files copied to "Dest_path" without issue, but "dest_path2" is getting hung on copying the files. It's formatting the folder names correctly, but it seems to think the files aren't there (they're there).

---

```
import os
import shutil
from shutil import copyfile
import time
import datetime

today = datetime.date.today()
today2 = today.strftime("%d-%b-%Y")
os.mkdir("c:\\users\\<user>\\desktop\\TEST" + "-" + today2)

#establish paths
source_path = "C:\\Users\\<user>\\Desktop\\Downloaded\\"
dest_path = "C:\\Users\\<user>\\Desktop\\" 
dest_path2 = "C:\\Users\\<user>\\Desktop\\TEST - %s\\" %(today2)

#move files
for reports in os.listdir(source_path):
    if reports.startswith("EiS"):
        shutil.copyfile(source_path + reports, dest_path + reports)
        print(dest_path2)
        shutil.copyfile(source_path + reports, dest_path2 + reports)
        print(reports)
```

---

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\<user>\Desktop\copy_remote_3.py", line 22, in <module>
    shutil.copyfile(source_path + reports, dest_path2 + reports)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 97, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\<user>\\Desktop\\TEST - 08-Jul-2019\\<name of first file in source_path>'
```

Comment: You're missing probably path encode / escape spaces, use raw strings `r"your/path"`

Comment: Hi,
I tried changing dest_path2 to:
    dest_path2 = r"'C:\Users\<user>\Desktop\TEST - " + today2 + "\\"

And I get:
    IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('wb') or filename: "'C:\\Users\\<user>\\Desktop\\TEST - 08-Jul-2019\\<name of first file in source_path>"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have named the folder you created and the destination path slightly differently. The difference is imperceptible, but occurs with the string concatenations. Your best bet is to create the variable for the destination path and then use this in both the `mkdir` and `shutil` operations.

```
import os
import shutil
from shutil import copyfile
import time
import datetime

today = datetime.date.today()
today2 = today.strftime("%d-%b-%Y")

#establish paths
source_path = "C:\\Users\\<user>\\Desktop\\Downloaded\\"
dest_path = "C:\\Users\\<user>\\Desktop\\" 
dest_path2 = "C:\\Users\\<user>\\Desktop\\TEST - %s\\" %(today2)

#apart from re-ordering this is the main change in the code.
os.mkdir(dest_path2)


#move files
for reports in os.listdir(source_path):
    if reports.startswith("EiS"):
        shutil.copyfile(source_path + reports, dest_path + reports)
        print(dest_path2)
        shutil.copyfile(source_path + reports, dest_path2 + reports)
        print(reports)
```

I made this change and it worked on some test cases.